# Bootstrap Over React bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using simple bootstrap in my react projects.
I want to ask experts that it is good technique or not? because sometimes I found react-bootstrap difficult to understand. IN simple words I want to ask that can we use simple bootstrap in react-js instead of react-bootstrap?

I want the answers that is this okay or not?

Comment: If you're using BS JS you may run into issues eventually because it's essentially two things messing with the DOM. If you're not using the JS *(or not using it much)* it can be just fine. That said, react-bootstrap isn't terribly confusing--if anything it's a simplification over mixing the two.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use `react-bootstrap`.

When you use `bootstrap` package in React.js, everything works perfectly fine related to Bootstrap CSS, ie , all the styling works fine.

However, the JavaScript file has issues of not working perfectly on React.js. A solution is to use `react-bootstrap` package with bootstrap.

React-Bootstrap replaces the Bootstrap JavaScript. Each component has been built from scratch as a true React component, without unneeded dependencies like jQuery.

**react-bootstrap** is pretty straight forward and is the same as using any other react component and comes with the same default styling and properties of normal bootstrap components.